# If $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)} = 2$ then find $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+3x)}{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)} = 2$ then find $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+3x)}{f(x)}$$
I tried to solve this problem but I only got that $f(x)>\sin x$ (I hope). But I can't procceed further. Any hints?

Comment: @Sebastiano God no.

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{2}$ by L'hopitals. $\lim x\to 0 \frac{\sin(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$, so $\lim x\to 0 \frac{\cos(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$. Hence $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+3x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{(f'(x))(1+3x)} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: $$\frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\frac{\log(1+3x)}{\sin(x)}}{\frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)}}$$

Comment: so in other words $f(x) = 2x$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst i think that answer is $\frac{3}{2}$. Your last derivative is not right. You forgot to multiply by 3

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+3x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{f(x)}\frac{x}{\sin x}\frac{\ln(1+3x)}{x}=\frac12\cdot3=\frac32.$$

Comment: Is it right my initial supposition? My +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano, we could say that $f(x)=2x+o(x)$ but not $f(x)=2x$.

Comment: Simplest answer (+1). Laws of limits are more powerful than beginners think of them. Ironically they are not the first weapon of choice for most beginners.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\sin x\sim_{x\to 0} x$$ and

$$\ln (1+x)\sim_{x\to 0} x$$

Comment: Hi, and excuse me, now I'm deleting not useful my comments.